# Exclude results from query if relationship in table exists

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have two tables:

`posts` table:

```
id | user_id | message
----------------------
 1 |      24 | hello
 2 |      96 | world
...
```

`posts_seen` table:

```
id | user_id | post_id
----------------------
 1 |      24 |       2
 2 |      96 |       1
```

The second table, `posts_seen`, simply tracks which posts have been "seen" (or read) by a user. For example, user #24 has seen post #2.

In my `Post.php` model, I have this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'posts';

    public function seen()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\PostSeen');
    }
}
```

However, when I query posts, *I want to exclude posts that have already been seen by the user*. Right now, I only have this:

```
$posts = Post::with('seen')
    ->get();
```

I want to modify this so that, if I am user #24, the query **should not** return post #2 since I have already seen it.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

What you should do is use the method `whereNotExists` in your query builder, like this:

```
$posts = Post::whereNotExists(function ($query) {
    $query->select(DB::raw(1))
          ->from('posts_seen')
          ->whereRaw('posts_seen.user_id = posts.user_id');
})
->get();
```

Note that I'm also assuming that you don't need the `seen` relationship anymore. If I'm wrong, you can just call the `with` again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:
First select the **post ids** which are seen by user identified by `user_id`

```
$posts_seen = PostSeen::where('user_id',$user_id)->get()->lists('post_id');
```

Then Select all the posts excluding **post ids** in `$posts_seen` using `whereNotIn()` method.

> The **whereNotIn** method verifies that the given column's value is not
>   contained in the given array:

```
Post::whereNotIn('id',$posts_seen)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use `whereDoesntHave`

Add a relationship count / exists condition to the query with where clauses.

```
$posts = Post::whereDoesntHave('seen', function($query) use ($request){
            $query->where('user_id', $request->user()->id);
        })
->get();
```